# Excel VBA macro to format cells

Tags: excel, vba, format

I've written an Excel sub that includes duplicate code, where the active range is formatted in a particular way, but I don't think it's possible to combine these cases into a loop.
Is it possible to write a separate sub/function that takes an input range, formats it, and outputs that formatted range, like python would with definable functions?

EDIT: Here's some barebones pseudocode

```
function Colour_and_Merge(Input Range)
    Formatted range = *Input Range with text and background colour changed*

    Colour_and_Merge = Formatted Range
end function

sub Main_Code()

for y = 1 to 3
    if y <> 1
        Colour_and_merge(Range(Cells(1,y),Cells(5,y)))
    end if

Colour_and_Merge(Seperate_Range)

end sub
```

Comment: can you please the codes that you have written, so that we can review and correct

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Comment: Yes. That's definitely possible. Subs can take objects. ```Private Function Frmt(rng As Range) As Range```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do that like below.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub ColorAndMerge(ByVal InputRange As Range)
    With InputRange
        .Interior.Color = vbRed  ' format range background red.
        .Font.Bold = True        ' format font bold
        'what ever you like to do with that range put it here
    End With
End Sub


Public Sub MainCode()
    Dim y As Long
    For y = 1 To 3
        If y > 1 Then
            ColorAndMerge Range(Cells(1, y), Cells(5, y)) 'make sure you specify in which workbook and worksheet your `Range` and `Cells` objects are!
        End If
    Next y

    ColorAndMerge SeperateRange
End Sub
```

Note that you don't need a `Function` but a `Sub`. It does not make any sense to return the range as it is the same range you sent in as `InputRange`. So for example if you call
`ColorAndMerge SeperateRange` in your main procedure you don't need `ColorAndMerge` to return anything because it would only return the same as `SeperateRange` which you already know.

So if your main code does the following

```vb
Public Sub MainCode()
    Dim SeperateRange As Range
    Set SeperateRange = Range(Cells(1, y), Cells(5, y))

    ColorAndMerge SeperateRange 'if you call the procedure

    'here `SeperateRange` will be the formatted range. There is no need to return it in a function, the SeperateRange variable is just a reference to the real range in the worksheet that already got formatted by ColorAndMerge 
End Sub
```

Also note that calling procedures/subs has to be **without** parenthesis while functions are called **with** parenthesis:

```
ColorAndMergeSub SeperateRange    ' correct
ColorAndMergeSub (SeperateRange)  ' wrong! ... this syntax exists but does something entirely differnt than the first one
ReturnValue = ColorAndMergeFunction(SeperateRange)  ' correct
ReturnValue = ColorAndMergeFunction SeperateRange   ' wrong!
```